# Using failWith with Servant and custom monad stack

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, servant

I'm using *Servant* with custom monad stack:

```
newtype AppHandler a = AppHandler { runHandler :: ReaderT Config (ExceptT ServantErr IO) a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Config, MonadError ServantErr, MonadIO)

data Config = Config
    { getPool :: ConnectionPool }
```

Now, in many handlers I just need to do fetch some data (Persistent) from db and act upon it, so I've got:

```
runDb :: (MonadReader Config m, MonadIO m) => SqlPersistT IO b -> m b
runDb query = do
  pool <- asks getPool
  liftIO $ runSqlPool query pool
```

As it turns out, when fetching from db, you're bound to work with `Maybe`, and quite often when the Maybe is `Nothing`, you just want to throw error so that Servant server will turn it into proper HTTP response. This led me to the discovery of `Control.Error.Util` and the `(!?) :: Applicative m => m (Maybe a) -> e -> ExceptT e m a` helper. So I tried following:

```
someHandler :: AppHandler NoContent
someHandler = do
  entity <- (runDb $ getCompanyByName companyName) !? err400
  -- some more logic
  return NoContent
```

But this does not compile, the result of `!?` here is `ExceptT ServantErr m0 (Entity SomeEntity)` but I no longer work with such handler type, it requires the `AppHandler (Entity SomeEntity)`. How would I convert such value back to my handler type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a variant of `(!?)` that is polymorphic in which monad it returns. For example:

```
(!??) :: MonadError e m => m (Maybe a) -> e -> m a
act !?? err = act >>= maybe (throwError err) return
```

Then, provided `err400 :: ServantError` -- which is the type of errors you declared `AppHandler` to have -- you will be able to write

```
runDb (getCompanyByName companyName) !?? err400
```

Comment: This works, however, I'm bit puzzled I've had to write my own helper for that, I expected I could use something existing and compose (probably with some lifting). Wouldn't it be possible without writing new helper?

Comment: @Bartosz, you can open an issue or file a pull request with Daniel's code here: https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Errors-Library/issues, and then everyone in the future won't have to write their own helper :)

Answer (score 1):

In general to convert a value of type `m a` to `ReaderT r m a` just use `lift`.

So perhaps this will work for you:

```
entity <- lift $ (runDb $ getCompanyByName companyName) !? err400
```

if the entire `(runDb ...) !? err400` is an `ExceptT ServantError ...` value.

Also, this servant issue discussion:

https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/286

might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, lift was my first intuition, however, compiler couldn't match `t0 (ExceptT ServantErr m0)` with `AppHandler`. There is no MonadTrans instance for AppHandler and I had troubles deriving/making one, as the kind of the AppHandler didn't match what MonadTrans expected.

Comment: I think you can get away with just a `type` for `AppHandler` - e.g. `type AppHandler = ReaderT Config (ExceptT ServantErr IO)`. You still need to use `!??` though.